# swift REST request with certificate returns errors (code -999)

Tags: json, swift, rest, ssl-certificate, alamofire

So I have a request to my server for logging in (I pass login, password and deviceId). As the result I get "token" as a String. I need also to add a certificate to access my REST.

But my code is not working.

```
class RestService {

private init(){}
static let shared = RestService()
var loginData:NSDictionary?


class func getCertificates() -> [SecCertificate]{
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "certf", withExtension: "cer")!
    let localCertificate = try! Data(contentsOf: url) as CFData
    guard let certificate = SecCertificateCreateWithData(nil, localCertificate) else {return[]}
    return [certificate]
}

let almgr:Alamofire.SessionManager = {
    let certificates = getCertificates()
    let trustPolicy = ServerTrustPolicy.pinCertificates(certificates: certificates, validateCertificateChain: true, validateHost: true)
    let serverTrustPolicies = ["liper":trustPolicy]
    let serverTrustPolicyManager = ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies)

    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = Alamofire.SessionManager.defaultHTTPHeaders
    let man = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default, serverTrustPolicyManager: serverTrustPolicyManager)
    return man
}()


func loginRest(login:String, password:String, deviceId:String){
            let urlStr = RestServices.REST_MAIN_URL + RestServices.REST_LOGIN
            let params = ["login":login, "password":password, "deviceId":deviceId]
            let headers: HTTPHeaders = ["Content-Type": "application/json"]

            RestService.shared.almgr.request(urlStr, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { (response) in
                let _ =  RestService.shared.almgr
                switch response.result {
                case .success:
                    print("\(self.TAG), receiving response from login with \(response)")
                    guard let receivedResponse = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: response.data!, options: []) as? [String:Any] else {
                        print("\(self.TAG), Error parsing response from login for json")
                        return
                    }
                    if let token:String = receivedResponse["token"] as? String {
                        print("\(self.TAG), \(token)")
                    } else {
                        print("\(self.TAG), error receiving token")
                        if let errorMessage:String = receivedResponse["status"] as? String {
                            print("\(self.TAG), error message for login with received response status: \(errorMessage)")
                        }
                        return
                    }


                case .failure(let error):
                    print("\(self.TAG), error receiving response for login with \(error)")
                    return
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

So whenever I call that login request method in my controller (for ex. after pressing button to login), I get following errors:

```
2018-01-17 15:43:16.129249+0100 ios-moe[5716:2789249] Task <67AFC6DA-9EFB-47D2-A5B0-FDAA3CC5285A>.<4> HTTP load failed (error code: -999 [1:89])
2018-01-17 15:43:16.129275+0100 ios-moe[5716:2789364] Task <67AFC6DA-9EFB-47D2-A5B0-FDAA3CC5285A>.<4> finished with error - code: -999
```

I am 100% sure that I am passing proper values and making a proper request, but I always get those errors. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: add in info.plist maybe it solve :  <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>

Comment: I added those but that didn't solve my problem. Anyway I found what was the problem.. I forgot to put port in my trust policies hostname.. Also don't know why I had to add ".disableEvaluation" for the host, but that without adding port number.. Thats so weird.. Anyway, thanks again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured it out. The problem was in defining trust policies:

```
let almgr:Alamofire.SessionManager = {
    let certificates = getCertificates()
    let trustPolicy = ServerTrustPolicy.pinCertificates(certificates: certificates, validateCertificateChain: true, validateHost: true)
// Here I had to modify that dict: (with port and with .disableEvaluation)
    let serverTrustPolicies = ["liper:8000":trustPolicy, "liper":.disableEvaluation]
    let serverTrustPolicyManager = ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies)

    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = Alamofire.SessionManager.defaultHTTPHeaders
    let man = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default, serverTrustPolicyManager: serverTrustPolicyManager)
    return man
}()
```

Work well now. What is weird, that I have to add port to the certificate pinning, cause without it I get ATS error about wrong certificate. And also the .disableEvaluation has to be without port.. Also, as @MAhipal Singh mentioned, I had to modify info.plist:

"add in info.plist maybe it solve : NSAppTransportSecurity  NSAllowsArbitraryLoads  "